# Duplicate comment when using the wp_insert_comment() function

Tags: wordpress, function

Whenever I update a page, I try to post a comment in WordPress automatically.

I created the function below, but the problem is that it posts the comment twice (duplicated).

```
function my_project_updated_send_email( $post_id, $post, $update ) {

    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    $data = array(
        'comment_post_ID'      => $post_id,
        'comment_content'      => 'This item was updated to version' . do_shortcode('[field "Version"]'),
        'user_id'              => $current_user->ID,
        'comment_type' => '',
    );

    wp_insert_comment( $data );
}
add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'my_project_updated_send_email', 10, 3 );
```

I only want to post the comment once.

[image: Duplicted comment]

How do I fix it?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue you're facing is related to the fact that the wp_insert_comment function is being triggered twice. This can happen because the wp_insert_post action hook fires twice during the process of updating a post, which is causing your comment to be duplicated.

To avoid this duplication, you can modify your code by adding a check to ensure that the comment is only added once. You can use a flag to keep track of whether the comment has already been added or not. Here's how you can do it:

```
function my_project_updated_send_email( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
// Check if the comment has already been added
if ( get_post_meta( $post_id, '_comment_added', true ) ) {
    return;
}

$current_user = wp_get_current_user();

$data = array(
    'comment_post_ID'      => $post_id,
    'comment_content'      => 'This item was updated to version ' . do_shortcode('[field "Version"]'),
    'user_id'              => $current_user->ID,
    'comment_type'         => '',
);

// Insert the comment
wp_insert_comment( $data );

// Set a meta flag to indicate that the comment has been added
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_comment_added', true );}
add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'my_project_updated_send_email', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: It partially worked. Now when I update the version from 1 to 1.1, it adds a comment, but when I update the version again to 1.2 it doesn't add any comment

Comment: The issue you're encountering might be related to how the _comment_added meta flag is being handled.   $current_version = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'Version', true );
    // Check if the comment has already been added or if the version has changed
    if ( get_post_meta( $post_id, '_comment_added', true ) || ! $update ) {
        return;
    }

Comment: Still doesn't work. Can you update the code for me please so I'll just copy it? I may type it wrong.